# Node.js getitem from dynamoDB and pass variable

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I'm working on some labmda code in Node.js, and I want to pass an item gotten from DynamoDB with getitem to some code. Here's what I have:

```
const Alexa = require('ask-sdk'); 
const AWS = require ('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});
//replace dynamo later with dynamo
dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();
//const appId = 'REPLACE WITH YOUR SKILL APPLICATION ID';

const date = new Date(Date.now()).toString();
const date2 = date.substring(0,16);
const time = date.substring(16,24);

const LaunchRequestHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        //first we assign the requestEnvelope request to the request variable
        const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
        //conditions to determine the requests this handler can handle
        //now using the request variable, we return true if it equals the one we want
        //in this case LaunchRequest
        return request.type === 'LaunchRequest'
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        //execution logic for the handler
        // ie What exactly do we do
        const speechOutput = 
            "Welcome to Track it, you can tell me who you lent things to, \
            or where you put an item. For example I lent the saw to Mike, or I put the saw in the workshop."
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speechOutput)
            .getResponse();
    }
}


const GaveIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
      return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
        && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'GaveIntent';
    },
    handle(handlerInput,event) {
        // setting variable attributes to handle things like counters
        const attributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();
        // personName and itemName are pulling the slots information from the intent
        const personName = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.lenderPerson.value;
        const itemName = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.storedObject.value;
        const currentUser = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.session.user.userId;

       //begin DB code
       var params = {
        TableName: 'TrackItDB',
        Item: {
          'userID' : {S: currentUser},
          'storedObject' : {S: itemName},
          'lenderPerson' : {S: personName},
          'objectStatus' : {S: 'lent'},
          'transactionDate': {S: date},
        },
        ConditionExpression: 'attribute_not_exists(storedObject)'
      };
      console.log(params);

// putItem in database only if it doesn't already exist
    dynamodb.putItem(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error", err);
            console.log("That item already exists");
                } else {
            console.log("Success", data);
                }
               });

        console.log(personName);
        console.log(itemName);
        console.log(currentUser);

        const speechOutput = 'You Gave ' + personName + ' the ' + itemName;

      return handlerInput.responseBuilder
        .speak(speechOutput)
        .withSimpleCard('Track It', speechOutput)
        .getResponse();
    }
  };

const PutIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
      return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
        && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'PutIntent';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const itemName = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.storedObject.value;
        const LocationName = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.storageLocation.value;
        const currentUser = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.session.user.userId;


       //begin DB code
       var params = {
        TableName: 'TrackItDB',
        Item: {
          'userID' : {S: currentUser},
          'storedObject' : {S: itemName},
          'lenderPerson' : {S: LocationName},
          'objectStatus' : {S: 'stored'},
          'transactionDate': {S: date},
        },
        ConditionExpression: 'attribute_not_exists(storedObject)'
      };

      dynamodb.putItem(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error", err);
            console.log("That item already exists");
        }
        else {
            console.log("Success", data);
        }
    });
       //end DB code
       const speechOutput = 'You put the ' + itemName + ' in the ' + LocationName;

      return handlerInput.responseBuilder
        .speak(speechOutput)
        .withSimpleCard('Hello World', speechOutput)
        .getResponse();
    }
  };

const WhereIsIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
      return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
        && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'WhereIsIntent';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const itemName = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.storedObject.value;
        const currentUser = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.session.user.userId;
// begin DB query
      var params = {
        Key: {
         "userID": {
           S: currentUser
          }, 
         "storedObject": {
           S: itemName
          }
        }, 
        TableName: "TrackItDB"
       };
// End DB Query


       dynamodb.getItem(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("Error", err); 
              }// an error occurred
        else  {   
        console.log("Success", data);           // successful response
        const LocationName = data.Item.lenderPerson.S; 
        const speechOutput = 'Your ' + itemName + ' is in the ' + LocationName;

         return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speechOutput)
            .withSimpleCard('Hello World', speechOutput)
            .getResponse();    
              }
        }); 

    }
  };

const HelpIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
         && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.HelpIntent';
},
handle(handlerInput) {
    const speechOutput = 'Welcome to Track it, you can tell me who you lent things to, or where you put an item. For example I lent the saw to Mike, or I put the saw in the workshop.';

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
        .speak(speechOutput)
        .reprompt(speechOutput)
        .withSimpleCard('Hello World', speechOutput)
        .getResponse();
    }
};

const CancelAndStopIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
         && (handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.CancelIntent'
           || handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.StopIntent');

    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const speechOutput = 'Goodbye!';

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speechOutput)
            .withSimpleCard('Hello World', speechOutput)
            .getResponse();
    }
};

const SessionEndedRequestHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'SessionEndedRequest';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        //any cleanup logic goes here
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder.getResponse();
    }
};


const skillBuilder = Alexa.SkillBuilders.custom();
exports.handler = skillBuilder
    .addRequestHandlers(
        LaunchRequestHandler,
        GaveIntentHandler,
        PutIntentHandler,
        WhereIsIntentHandler,
        HelpIntentHandler,
        SessionEndedRequestHandler,
        CancelAndStopIntentHandler
    )
    .lambda()
```

I'm trying to pass the "itemName and LocationName to the const speechOutput variable so I can have [Alexa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Alexa) speak it for me.

It will work in the console log, but not later outside the getitem function. FYI, I know I shouldn't have the const speechOutput twice, and it isn't like that in my code; I just put it there to show what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the responseBuilder code snippet within the `getItem` function' `else` part. 
Do not declare the const `speechOutput` twice.

```
handle(handlerInput) {
    const itemName =
        handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.storedObject.value;
    const currentUser =
        handlerInput.requestEnvelope.session.user.userId;

    // Begin database query
    var params = {
        Key: {
            "userID": {
                S: currentUser
            },
            "storedObject": {
                S: itemName
            }
        },
        TableName: "TrackItDB"
    };
    // End DB Query

    //const speechOutput = 'test'
    dynamodb.getItem(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error", err);
    } // An error occurred
    else {
        console.log("Success", data); // Successful
                                      // response
        const LocationName = data.Item.lenderPerson.S;
        const speechOutput = 'Your ' + itemName + ' is in the ' +
                             LocationName;
        // Speak the output
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speechOutput)
            .withSimpleCard('Hello, World!', speechOutput)
            .getResponse();
        console.log(speechOutput);
    }
});
//const speechOutput = 'Your ' + itemName + ' is in the ' +
                     LocationName;
}
```

Comment: The indentation is a mess. I am not sure if you have changed anything, but you may be able to use content from the fixed question.

Comment: Thanks, @PeterMortensen for pointing that out. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: OK So I've tried this, and While I no longer get any error, I also don't get any speech output.

Comment: Hi Guys, I've edited the original question and added the complete code in hopes someone can help me. Thanks